# WordPress "Billing Name and Address" fields block not displaying

Tags: wordpress

On our contribution page, I can select the amount and confirm, but then on the final screen the Billing Name and Address fields block does not display at all.

Comment: Please include the version of CiviCRM and the payment processor you are using.

Comment: Does it display on the first page and allow you to submit values?

Answer (score 1):

This site was hacked prior to me working on it. I ended up restoring a backed up version of the plugin folder and the "files" folder. Now everything is working fine.